# ESI include on akamai setup

Tags: akamai, esi

I have a static HTML site, stored within Akamai's NetStorage. I have been looking into ESI so that I can include content within other pages, e.g. include navigation.html on all pages.

Akamai have produced some good documentation around the structure of the tags, e.g.

```
<esi:include src="navigation.html"/>
```

However, is there something I am missing?
When I add the tag to the page and upload the to the NetStorage account, the server is not processing this. Is there something that needs setting up in the Property Manager with Akamai's Luna Control Center that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to provide more information before i comment on what needs to be done. Are there two origins? I mean one is your origin server and another netstorage?

And have you added ESI in your property manager configuration? If not then you should.